# Pandas: IndexError: index out of bounds when using iterrows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm encountering a bit of a strange problem, and I don't know what's causing it exactly. I am attempting to use iterrows to loop through a subset of columns and update a new column based on the findings within the current column's row. It seems to  be working for one list that I have, but not the other. I've converted all columns in each list to strings, but that doesn't seem to solve it.

Example:

```
list1 = [item for item in list(df) if 'TR_' in item]

list2 = [item for item in list(df) if 'TS_' in item ]



for index, row in df[list1].iterrows():
   print(index, row)
   if pd.isna(row[index]):
      df.loc[index, 'new_col'] = 'good'
   else:
      df.loc[index, 'new_col'] = "bad"


for index, row in df[list2].iterrows():
   print(index, row)
   if pd.isna(row[index]):
      df.loc[index, 'new_col2'] = 'good'
   else:
      df.loc[index, 'new_col2'] = 'bad'

output:
```

> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py
>   in get_value(self, series, key)    3102             return
>   self._engine.get_value(s, k,
>   -> 3103                                           tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))    3104         except KeyError
>   as e1:
>
> pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()
>
> pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()
>
> pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> KeyError: 3
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        17 for index, row in df[list2].iterrows():
>        18     print(index, row)
>   ---> 19     if pd.isna(row[index]):
>        20         df.loc[index, 'new_col2'] = 'Compliant'
>        21     else:
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in
>   **getitem**(self, key)
>       764         key = com._apply_if_callable(key, self)
>       765         try:
>   --> 766             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
>       767 
>       768             if not is_scalar(result):
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py
>   in get_value(self, series, key)    3107     3108             try:
>   -> 3109                 return libindex.get_value_box(s, key)    3110             except IndexError:    3111                 raise
>
> pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.get_value_box()
>
> pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.get_value_box()
>
> IndexError: index out of bounds`

Comment: FYI... you can use `pd.DataFrame.filter` to filter you dataframe instead of list comprehension.  `df.filter(like='TR_').columns`

Comment: Is this ```pd.isna(row[index])``` actually correct ? Don't you call column number index, on your row, where index is row index ?

Comment: @ScottBoston- thank you! Great to know!

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski I believe so. It works on the first iterrows, giving the correct output, but not the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was referring to was:

```py
>>> df
  cat  col1  col2
0   a     1     2
1   a     3     2
2   b    23     1
3   a     1    23
4   b   121    32
>>> for index, row in df.iterrows():
...    print(row[index])
...
a
3
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Grzegorz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4723, in get_value
    return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 80, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 88, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1607, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 3

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Grzegorz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1064, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "C:\Users\Grzegorz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4729, in get_value
    return libindex.get_value_box(s, key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 51, in pandas._libs.index.get_value_box
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 47, in pandas._libs.index.get_value_at
  File "pandas\_libs\util.pxd", line 98, in pandas._libs.util.get_value_at
  File "pandas\_libs\util.pxd", line 89, in pandas._libs.util.validate_indexer
IndexError: index out of bounds
```

I.e. you use the `row[index]` wrong. What do you want to achieve there ?

**EDIT**

Replace :

```py
pd.isna(row[index])
```

with

```py
np.product(pd.isna(row))
```

By doing so - you will:

(1) return list of `True`/`False` per each column for given `row`

`pd.isna(row)`

(2) calculate logical multiplication (i.e. `a1 and a2 and ...`) so `True` only IF all the columns are `na`, otherwise `False`

`np.product(pd.isna(row))`

Comment: Ah- I see. I'm trying to go through all rows across each column and, if they're all blank, create a new column that says "good", otherwise create a new column that says "bad" and capture all of their information in a second new column for that row

Comment: Then try doing: ```pd.isna(row)``` - you will get back row with ```True/False``` per column, if given Column is ```na```. Question is - how do you want to take it from there i.e. one column is na == bad, or all column na == bad ?

Comment: Ah, that worked! if all columns are na = good, else bad + add all commentary to new cell

Comment: Please check my edit - this should solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting your index before the lists.

```
 df=df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: try using iloc since it is index based.